# Hover() jquery failed to work properly in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is my child is position absolute, I have to do it that way. I can't hover to the child using hover function because it's hover out from my selector. I spend few hours resolving this but failed.

My code as below :

```js
$(function () {
    $("#hdCallUs").hover(function () {
        $('.contact_numbers').show();
    }, function () {
        $('.contact_numbers').hide()
    });
});
```

```css
ul, li {
    list-style:none
}
#hdCallUs .call_txt {
    cursor: pointer;
    float:right;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 155px;
    background: #fff;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers li {
    padding: 8px;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers li:hover {
    background: #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hdCallUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
 <span class="call_txt">Call Now</span>

    <div class="contact_numbers" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <!-- added this -->
            <li>999</li>
            <li>888</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any solution?

Comment: `$("#hdCallUs, .contact_numbers").hover(function () {` _OR_ `$("#hdCallUs, #hdCallUs *").hover(function ()`

Comment: @Tushar tried, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $("#hdCallUs .call_txt").hover(function () {
        $('.contact_numbers').show();
    });

$("#hdCallUs").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('.contact_numbers').hide();
});


});
```

```css
ul, li {
    list-style:none
}
   
#hdCallUs {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}

#hdCallUs .call_txt {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block; 
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;

}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    top: 40px;
    width: 155px;
    background: #fff;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers li {
    padding: 8px;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#hdCallUs .contact_numbers li:hover {
    background: #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hdCallUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
 <span class="call_txt">Call Now</span>

    <div class="contact_numbers" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <!-- added this -->
            <li>999</li>
            <li>888</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: if u hover to call now and hover left, the child don't hide.

Comment: Try now, the float right was screwing up the height of the parent container.  The "Full page" button inside SO code view takes the mouse outside of the `hdCallUs` div - this shouldn't be a problem in your own site.

Comment: which line u changed?

Comment: From line 4 to 20 in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#hdCallUs").hover(function(){
     $('.contact_numbers').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $('.contact_numbers').hide();
});
```